# Bootstrap - Open off-canvas with GET Request PHP

Tags: php, get, bootstrap-5

Hi I am working on a project that use bootstrap. I have edit button and that button sends a get request. What I want to do is send that GET request and get it from the bootstrap off-canvas. My off-canvas opens with data-bs-target. Any help?

**`edit_album_item is the page where off-canvas included`**

My main page:

```
<?php include "includes/edit_album_item.php" ?>

                <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="row" style="position: absolute;">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <a href="index.php?delete=<?php echo $item_id ?>"><button class="btn btn-danger delete-card"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <a href="index.php?edit=<?php echo $item_id ?>#offcanvasAlbum" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasAlbum" aria-controls="offcanvasAlbum"><button class="btn btn-warning delete-card"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="includes/images/<?php echo $item_image ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="...">

                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $item_title ?></h5>
                            <p class="card-text"><?php echo $item_description ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

---

Actually the edit_album_item.php is not well developed yet. I want send a get request and open off-canvas get the information from the get request. Thanks in advance!

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaOuh.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I understand your question. To do this what you need to do is,
add anchor to your edit button to send get request like this

`index.php?yourreq`

and try this is on the bottom of your page

```
if(isset($_GET['your req'])) {

     echo '
          <script>
                 $("#offcanvasAlbumItem").modal("show");
          </script>
';

}
```

I think now you are good to go.

Comment: Worked brother!!!